# Can anything be said about the average value of X using its CDF?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, average, cumulative-distribution-functions

Marginal CDF of X:

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }x\in(-\infty,-3)\\
\frac{2x+11}{25}&x \in [-3,2)\\
1&x\in[2,\infty)
\end{cases}$$

Can we say anything about $X$’s average value?

I don’t think we can find the expected value of $X$, because $X$ is not absolutely continuous so we can’t find $X$’s pdf. Also, I said that $X$ is not a non-negative random variable so we can’t do that method either. When I think of saying something about $X$’s average value, I think of the expected value of $X$ or finding a bound of the average value. The latter I don’t think we can do either.

Am I missing something? Can we say anything about X’s average value?

Answer (score 1):

Your rv has 2 discontinuity points

$X=-3$ with probability $\frac{1}{5}$

$X=2$ with probability $\frac{2}{5}$

Thus the expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=-3\times\frac{1}{5}+\int_{-3}^{2}\frac{2}{25}xdx+2\times\frac{2}{5}=0$$

> so we can’t find X’s pdf.

Actually there is the possibility to derive a "mixed PDF" with two discrete points with probability $>0$

This is often used in [Telecommunication Enigineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_engineering)

Comment: I thought we wouldn't be able to find the E[X} because X isnt absolutely continuous and X is not a non-negative RV

Comment: also with your calculation, wouldn't E[X] be $$\mathbb{E}[X]=-3\times\frac{1}{5}+\int_{-3}^{2}\frac{2x+11}{25}dx+2\times\frac{3}{5}=2.37$$ or am i missing something. I used $$\frac{2x+11}{25}$$ for x = -3 and x = 2 and got 1/5 and 3/5

Comment: @Luka22 : AS you can see I did $\int_{-3}^2 \frac{2x}{25}dx$ that is $\int x f_X(x)dx$. You did $\int F_X(x)dx$ and it doesn's make sense. For $x=2$ you have $F(2)-F(2^-)=\frac{2}{5}$. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Random variable $X$ does not have a density function because it's distribution is not continuous. It does however have $E(X) =0$ as shown here. (+1) // $Y\sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4,p=0.5)$ does not have a density function either, but it has $E(Y) = 2.$.